# How to install csi tool on Galileo Gen2 board

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, intel-galileo

I have been working on Galileo Gen2 for installing CSI tool for several weeks.
I followed this link [Linux 802.11n CSI Tool — Installation Instructions](https://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/installation.html) to install it.
I tried to install it on both [debian system for Galileo](https://sourceforge.net/p/galileodebian/wiki/DebianOnGalileo/) and [Linux galileo 3.8.7-yocto-standard](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26418/Intel-Galileo-Board-Support-Package?wapkw=galileo)
However, I find that I need to install linux-headers which csi tool needs to recompile and change some kernel modules like iwlwifi as the following command shows.

> make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
> M=$(pwd)/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi modules

So,I tried to install kernel-headers for the Linux galileo 3.8.7-yocto-standard kernel.  However I can't find anything helpful for me to install the corresponding linux-headers.
Then I tried to compile kernel using [the source codes csi tool offered](https://github.com/dhalperi/linux-80211n-csitool) directly so that the kernel modules are what csi tool needs. I builded the kernel from 3.8.0 to 4.1.0 successfully using the original .config file  from 3.8.7-yocto-standard kernel. The correlative kernel files and kernel headers I need are also generated. (including initrd.img and vmlinuz in /boot/ and kernel headers in /lib/modules/)

I think the system boot configuration file is from the grub.conf from /boot/grub/grub.conf on the SD card first partition .The partial content of this file is on the following.

```
default 1
timeout 10

color white/blue white/cyan

title Clanton SVP kernel-SPI initrd-SPI IMR-On IO-APIC/HPET NoEMU
    kernel --spi root=/dev/ram0 console=ttyS1,115200n8 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,,$EARLY_CON_ADDR_REPLACE,115200n8 vmalloc=384M reboot=efi,warm apic=debug rw
    initrd --spi

title Custom Quark Kernel with Debian Wheezy
    root (hd0,3)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.7+ root=/dev/mmcblk0p4 3 console=ttyQRK1,115200n8 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,$EARLY_CON_ADDR_REPLACE,115200n8 vmalloc=3844M reboot=efi,warm apic=debug rw LABEL=boot debugshell=5
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.8.7+
```

I changed the part from 3.8.7+ to 3.8.0( because vmlinuz-3.8.0 and initrd.img-3.8.0 are generated in the same place of vmlinuz-3.8.7+ and initrd.img-3.8.7+)

But it just failed to load the 3.8.0 kernel after I changed the grub.conf file. It stopped on a place where I think initrd.img should be loaded.

[The booting windows picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUERQ.png)

Besides I find that the system intel offered is built through yocto. Does it mean that I need to build the system using yocto? If it does, I also want to make sure that how to add kernel headers when I build the system

So, the problem:How can I install csi tool on Galileo Gen2 changed into: How can I change kernel on the system or how can I install kernel headers for installing the kernel modules the csi tool needed.

I would appreciate it if you would help me solve these problems. Thanks a lot

Comment: You cannot run a "standard" kernel on gallileo as far as I know.  The documentation for Debian for Galileo says it uses the special galileo kernel. So I'd say replacing the kernel is a no-go. You should be able to build the correct kernel headers using the yocto resources available at the galileo download page.

Comment: Thanks for your advice very much.But I cant find the resources to add kernel headers at the galileo download page, as I'm a beginner of yocto.And I cant find specific information for adding kernel headers for Galileo. I would appreciate it if you could give me some references about how to add kernel headers when build yocto image.

Comment: Follow steps 2 and 3 in https://downloadmirror.intel.com/26418/eng/BSP-Patches-and-Build_Instructions.1.1.0.txt to build the firmware image. The kernel headers should be produced as part of the build.
It uses a fairly old yocto version which means you might run into problems building on a modern OS.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I followed the documentation Intel offered and built a full-featured linux image for SD card not the firmware image using yocto. Because I need a large space to install csi tool on the system. And I could not find kernel headers on the system. It seemed that I should add something to the yocto recipe so that the kernel headers can be generated. How do you think of it ?

Comment: @Ola, it's wrong. Upstream kernel works on Galileo starting from v4.14.

Comment: Just take whatever distribution you prefer and set it up on SD card. It needs kernel to be built as i586 + TSC UniProcessor. I shared BuildRoot scripts (as a fork of BuildRoot distribution sources) which allows you to create an image with custom kernel (kernel which is built separately): https://github.com/andy-shev/buildroot/tree/intel/board/intel/common

Comment: @0andriy  Thanks for your answer ! Do you mean that the kernel you offer can work on Galileo Gen2 Board ? I want to make sure whether I can build the kernel using your source codes which I can use it to replace the original kernel on Galileo Gen2 and add kernel headers. If I can add kernel headers , then I can use kernel headers to install csi tool.

Comment: What I referred to is **upstream** kernel (v5.10-rc5 as of today or earlier if you wish) which you can build separately. The link is to the BuildRoot Linux distribution that patched to support in particular disk image creation for Galileo Gen2 board. Perhaps I need to extend that scripts to build kernel as well...

Comment: https://github.com/andy-shev/linux/tree/galileo Kernel (minimum for Galileo Gen2) is there.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working please @ykkz? Would love to understand how if so!